# grid32.ocx not correctly registered in VB6

Tags: vb.net, vb6, ocx

I registered `grid32.ocx` in Windows 7 32bit. If I refer to it from a solution, I am getting the error "grid32.ocx not correctly registered".

Answer (score 0):

> I registered grid32.ocx

and then the computer tells you

> grid32.ocx not correctly registered

What does that tell you? It tells me *one of you* is lying. So: Are you sure you registered it **correctly**?

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded another grid32.ocx. Now its working Fine